# Using socat through Tor socks proxy gives no response

Tags: configuration, socks, private

I am trying to get an HTTP request through a private Tor network that I have setup using tunneling with `socat`.

In a private Tor network (`10.0.0.216/29`) I have relays setup on my servers 218 and 221 through which I am manually creating a circuit (`218 -> 221`). I have Apache running on 222 and hope to load the default page through a connected client.

I take 217 as a client and after creating the circuit, I use the following command:

```
curl --socks4a localhost:9050 10.0.0.222
```

This works successfully. Then I try to create a bidirectional tunnel using `socat` by the following command

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:9000 SOCKS4A:127.0.0.1:10.0.0.222:80,socksport=9050 &
```

And I try to access the same resource using `curl -v localhost:9000` but there is no response. The verbose output:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:9000/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:9000
> Accept: */*
>
```

The connection times out after some time. Here is the clause that continuously is repeated in the `info.log` debug log file.

```
Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [info] choose_good_exit_server_general(): Found 1 servers that might support 1/1 pending connections.
Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [info] choose_good_exit_server_general(): Chose exit server '$<fingerprint of OR221>~OR221 at 10.0.0.221'

Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [info] compute_weighted_bandwidths(): Empty routerlist passed in to consensus weight node selection for rule weight as guard
Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [info] smartlist_choose_node_by_bandwidth(): Empty routerlist passed in to old node selection for rule weight as guard
Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [info] router_choose_random_node(): We couldn't find any live, guard routers; falling back to list of all routers.
Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [info] compute_weighted_bandwidths(): Empty routerlist passed in to consensus weight node selection for rule weight as middle node
Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [info] smartlist_choose_node_by_bandwidth(): Empty routerlist passed in to old node selection for rule no weighting
Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [warn] No available nodes when trying to choose node. Failing.
Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [warn] No available nodes when trying to choose node. Failing.

Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [info] compute_weighted_bandwidths(): Empty routerlist passed in to consensus weight node selection for rule weight as guard
Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [info] smartlist_choose_node_by_bandwidth(): Empty routerlist passed in to old node selection for rule weight as guard
Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [info] router_choose_random_node(): We couldn't find any live, guard routers; falling back to list of all routers.
Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [info] compute_weighted_bandwidths(): Empty routerlist passed in to consensus weight node selection for rule weight as middle node
Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [info] smartlist_choose_node_by_bandwidth(): Empty routerlist passed in to old node selection for rule no weighting
Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [warn] No available nodes when trying to choose node. Failing.
Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [warn] No available nodes when trying to choose node. Failing.

Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [warn] Failed to find node for hop 0 of our path. Discarding this circuit.
Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [info] onion_populate_cpath(): Generating cpath hop failed.
Oct 07 13:19:52.000 [info] circuit_get_open_circ_or_launch(): No safe circuit (purpose 5) ready for edge connection; delaying.

Oct 07 13:19:53.000 [notice] Tried for 120 seconds to get a connection to 10.0.0.222:80. Giving up. (waiting for circuit)
```

Any help is appreciated.

PS: I am trying to use `socat` as torify and torsocks do not seem to work for connections having a local DNS address resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue trying use `socat` to run an application through the Tor socks proxy on Tails. I was trying this:

```
# socat TCP-LISTEN:1234 SOCKS4A:127.0.0.1:remoteip:5678,socksport=9050 &
$ telnet remoteip 5678
```

which gave

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I had a grope around `iptables` and realised that Tails restricts outgoing network packets, even on the loopback interface. I added a rule to allow connections to the port on the loopback device that `socat` listens to (in the above example that's port `1234`):

```
# iptables -I OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT
```

After which everything worked as expected.